# What is the difference between blocking and non-blocking sockets? (for realz edition)

Tags: linux, windows, networking, boost, udp

Before everybody marks this as a dup let me state that I know my fair share of network programming and this question is my attempt to solve something that riddles me even after finding the "solution".

## The setup

I've spend the last weeks writing some glue code to incorporate a big industrial system into our current setup. The system is controlled by a Windows XP computer (PC A) which is controlled from a Ubuntu 14.04 system (PC B) by sending a steady stream of UDP packets at 2000 Hz. It responds with UDP packets containing the current state of the system.

Care was taken to ensure that the the 2000 Hz rate was held because there is a 3ms timeout after which the system faults and returns to a safe state. This involves measuring and accounting for inaccuracies in `std::this_thread::sleep_for`. Measurements show that there is only a 0.1% derivation from the target rate.

## The observation

Problems started when I started to receive the state response from the system. The controlling side on *PC B* looks roughly like this:

```
forever at 2000Hz {
  send current command;
  if ( socket.available() >= 0 ) {
    receive response;
  }
}
```

**edit 2:** Or in real code:

```
auto cmd_buf = ...
auto rsp_buf = ...

while (true) {
   // prepare and send command buffer
   cmd_buf = ...
   socket.send(cmd_buf, endpoint);

   if (socket.available() >= 0) {
      socket.receive(rsp_buf);
      // the results are then parsed and stored, nothing fancy
   }

   // time keeping
}
```

Problem is that, whenever the receiving portion of the code was present on *PC B*, *PC A* started to run out of memory within seconds when trying to allocate *receive* buffers. Additionally it raised errors stating that the timeout was missed, which was probably due to packets not reaching the control software.

Just to highlight the strangeness: *PC A* is the pc *sending* UDP packets in this case.

**Edit in response to EJP:** this is the (now) working setup. It started out as:

```
forever at 2000Hz {
  send current command;
  receive response;
}
```

But by the time the response was received (blocking) the deadline was missed. Therefore the availability check.

Another thing that was tried was to receive in a seperate thread:

```
// thread A
forever at 2000Hz {
  send current command;
}

// thread B 
forever {
  receive response;
}
```

Which displays the same behavior as the first version.

## The solution

The solution was to set the socket on *PC B* to non blocking mode. One line and all problems were gone.

I am pretty sure that even in blocking mode the deadline was met. There should be no performance difference between blocking and non-blocking mode when there is just one socket involved. Even if checking the socket for available data takes some microseconds more than in non-blocking mode it shouldn't make a difference when the overall deadline is met accuratly.

Now ... what is happening here?

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree here. Checking a blocking-mode socket for `available() > 0` is a complete waste of time, and you should have just removed that test and left it in blocking mode. The following `read()` or `recv()` will block until data is available. If you need a read timeout, set a read timeout. And buffers to hold the incoming data should have already been allocated prior to the loop.

Comment: @EJP updated question. Regarding the timeout, I considered that, but the boost asio documentation is quite opaque imho.

Comment: What do you do when you receive the data?

Comment: @jpou I guess you suspect that I do some fancy processing slowing me down. But this is not the case and for testing purposes I actually removed all parsing after receiving and had the same problem.

Comment: I think we would need to see a MCVE for this one.  But 2000Hz sounds awfully high for a non-realtime OS.

Comment: @Harry a MCVE is hard to provide as the symptoms happen in the (proprietary) control system (ie *PC A*). I could provide our side of the code stripped down to just the networking, but I fear it won't be of much use.

Comment: If you can't replicate the problem with just the networking code, then I would have to assume that the problem isn't *in* the networking code. :-)

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "PC A is the pc sending UDP packets in this case" ?  The code you've shown for PC B seems to be sending UDP packets, and your description up to that point also said that B was sending packets.

Comment: Oh, one other thought - have you tried using a packet sniffer or network analyzer to see what the difference (if any) the blocking mode actually makes to the nature of the network traffic?

Comment: @HarryJohnston *I* can replicate it with just the network code, because I have access to the proprietary system on *PC A*. Both PCs are sending data, *PC B* is sending position commands, *PC A* is responding with current positions. Trying to receive them on *PC B* causes memory allocation errors in *PC A*. I am not sure if I am allowed to run packet sniffers on our network, I'll ask around.

Comment: Oh, I see - someone else's code on PC A, so you can't post even just that part of it.  In principle you should be able to write some code of your own that demonstrates the same behaviour, but under the circumstances I can see why you don't want to do that much work!  If you aren't allowed to run a packet sniffer on the main network, you might want to consider whether it would be possible to temporarily put the two PCs onto an isolated network for that purpose - perhaps as simple as a cross-over cable linking the two directly, with a packet sniffer running on PC B.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly and referring to this code:

```
forever at 2000Hz {
  send current command;
  receive response;
}
```

Examine the difference between the blocking and not blocking socket. With blocking socket you send current command and then you are stuck waiting for the response. By this time I would guess you already miss the 2kHz goal.

Now in non blocking socket you send the current command, try to received whatever is in receive buffers, but if there is nothing there you return immediately and continue your tight 2kHz loop of sending. This explains to me why your industrial control system works fine in non-blocking code.

Comment: That's what the availability check in the first snippet is for.